# Nx print a list of affected projects

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx-monorepo

I see that Nx is [deprecating](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/17341) the `print-affected` command. The alternatives given does not produce the output I want.

Right now, I am using `nx print-affected --target=<script name>` which tells me which projects are affected for that target. I am not seeing a way to do this with either `show projects`, `graph` or `affected`. The closest command I see is `show projects` with the `--affected` flag, but it does not accept a `target`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nx show projects --affected --with-target build` should accomplish your goal

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I had an older version of Nx in the node_modules even though package.json has a newer version. That's why I didn't see this in the `--help` section.